# Error while trying to deploy App42 Custom-Code

Tags: java, custom-code, app42

I'm trying to deploy my custom code in App42 and keep getting the following error message:

```
Class can not be used in custom code deployment java.lang.Class : in source
com.shephertz.app42.paas.customcode.chat.update.GenericCallback$OperationStatus
```

what does that error means, if my class violates any restrictions of the java sandbox shouldn't the message be clearer?

Comment: Are you using any internal class in your code? Internal classes are not allowed to be used inside custom code. If you still think it is really needed for you and you can not proceed without that, send your code to us for review and we will update your further on that.

Comment: @ajay no i was just using an enum, i got rid of it and everything went fine, the message doesn't give any information about what's wrong, plus, no enums! really! I can always work without enums but WHY! P.S. I have internal classes and I didn't have any problem with that.

Comment: Sorry for confusion...We removed internal class usage restriction earlier. For enum usage I have logged the issue and will update you once it is available for use.